# Writing Perl libraries

Tags: perl, oop

I have been learning Perl for the past few weeks and I have made decent progress in learning the language. After reading various forums I came to know that it's better to write libraries than writing stand alone programs. I have absolutely no clue about writing libraries but I'd like to learn it. Can some body help me with this?

My understanding is we have the main script in .pm and call it from .pl. Correct me if im wrong.

If the below code is in time.pm,

- How do I call it from .pl?
- How do I pass the value of `$t` from .pl?

time.pm:

```
while(1)
{
       $Time = join ':', (localtime(time))[2, 1, 0];
       if ($Time eq  my $t)
        {
           //code 
           print ($time);
        }
}
```

Comment: Simple: to make some more _decent_ progress, read the Modern Perl book. http://modernperlbooks.com/mt/index.html and buy the "Programming in Perl" (http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596004927.do ;). Your question is covered in depth.

Comment: Backwards. Program goes in .pl. Reusable bits goes into the module (.pm).

Answer (score 0):

You need to have your main code in a .pl file that you would run. The library or module that you are building would go into a .pm file.

Inside of your main perl file (.pl) you need to include the module (.pm) file you wrote with something like:

use newmodule;

If you run into issues with it not finding the module you need to make sure that it is in perl's library path.

Once the module is included in your perl script you will be able to invoke it's functions.